# Delete Function clicking on checkbox passing id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have grid in which check box is added for every row. When i click on Delete button without clicking check box it says "Please select one at least one row to perform". when clicking on check box will also displays same message. Please help me find out the solution and mistake i have done in the mentioned code below.

```
     //Calling Delete function clicking on checkbox
                $(document).ready(function () { 
    //Grid Function
     $.ajax(
                                {
                                    url: "GetCompanyTypeMasterDetails",
                                    type: "get",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    contentType: "application/json",
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        $("#grid").igGrid({
                                            autoGenerateColumns: false,
                                            primaryKey: "CompanyTypeID",
                                            columns: [

                                                { headerText: "Company Type ID", key: "CompanyTypeID", dataType: "Numeric", hidden: true },
                                                {
                                                    headerText: "", key: "CompanyTypeID", dataType: "Numeric", width: "80",
                                                    template: '<table><tr><td><input type="image" src="/Images/GridImages/edit.png" onclick = "EditRecords(${CompanyTypeID})"  /></td><td><input type="image" src="/Images/GridImages/delete.png" onclick = "DeleteRecords(${CompanyTypeID})" /></td></tr></table>'
                                                },
                                                { headerText: "", key:"CompanyTypeID", dataType:"Numeric", width:"50", template: '<input type="checkbox" id="chkID" />'},
                                                { headerText: "Company Type", key: "CompanyTypeName", dataType: "string", width: "600" },
                                                { headerText: "Company Code", key: "Code", dataType: "string", width: "600" },


                                            dataSource: data}
});
                $("#btnDelete").click(function (ID) {
                                var isSelected = $('#chkID').is(':checked');
                                if (!isSelected) {
                                    alert("Please select atleast one row to perform this action");
                                }
                                else if (isSelected) {
                                    DeleteRecords(ID);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                });

            //Delete Function
                        function DeleteRecords(ID) {
                            $.ajax(
                                    {
                                        url: "DeleteRecords",
                                        type: "post",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        data: {CompanyTypeID : ID},
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            alert("Are you sure you want to Delete?");
                                            location.reload();
                                        },
                                        error: function (status) {
                                            alert(status.responseText);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
```

Comment: You are using same id for every delete button and checkbox, use different ids or use class.

Comment: show us how you are adding rows to grid.

Comment: you want a solution for what problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#chkID')` refers to an element with id = chkID. I think that you problem here is that you have multiple checkboxes with the same id.

Possible solution could be: adding to all your checkboxes a class (lets say 'chkBox'):

```
$("#btnDelete").click(function (ID) {
     if ($('.chkBox:checked').length == 0) {
         alert("Please select atleast one row to perform this action");
     }
     else {
         DeleteRecords(ID);
     }
});
```

Here is working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k20ga1bg/)

Comment: He asked to find a mistake and this is a mistake!

Comment: you're right. The question is pretty vague, I was assuming he didn't want to display the message when ticking the checkbox. Removing donwvote...

Comment: If i click Delete button without clicking checkbox the msg will be displayed properly. but my problem is even after clicking checkbox and then Delete button it displays same msg as when it s not clicked.

Comment: Try the solution i just proposed, i think it will resolve your issue

Comment: Well, it works in jsFiddle (the link is attached), so i assume you have a problem somewhere else in the code...